# How to performantly create circles or shapes in C# bitmap?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, bitmap, rendering

(Wall of text, please let me know if there is not enough information!)

I'm working on a program which makes a lot of circles (as few as 10, but can scale exponentially). I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of this process. One circle is used as the "base", and every other circle is "subtracted" from the base. For an example, think of a cookie or other circular object with small bites taken out of the edge.

Originally, I used Vector2 arrays or Lists to define the areas and perimeters of every circle, then found vectors which matched in the areas of the base circles and circles to subtract, and then removed them from the base. This can go pretty quickly when the circles only count up to 100 or even 1000, but by 10000 it becomes very slow (several minutes) and anything beyond that can take over an hour.

The perimeter definition method:

```
public override void DefinePerimeter()
        {
            perimeter = new List<Vector2>();

            //Find one quadrant worth of perimeter
            //Mirror x,y values to form full circle

            for(float i = 0; i < 90; i += resolutionFactor)
            {
                float cos = radius * MathF.Cos(i);
                float sin = radius * MathF.Sin(i);

                perimeter.Add(new Vector2((int)(center.X + cos), (int)(center.Y - sin)));
                perimeter.Add(new Vector2((int)(center.X - cos), (int)(center.Y - sin)));
                perimeter.Add(new Vector2((int)(center.X - cos), (int)(center.Y + sin)));
                perimeter.Add(new Vector2((int)(center.X + cos), (int)(center.Y + sin)));
            }
            perimeter = RemoveDuplicates(perimeter);//Removes duplicate Vector2
```

The area definition:

```
if (perimeterDefined == true && perimeter.Count>1)
            {
                Vector2 yBounds = Bounding.GetYBounds(perimeter);
                if(yBounds.Y-yBounds.X>0)
                {
                    List<Vector2> yLevel = new List<Vector2>();
                    for (int i = (int)yBounds.X; i < (int)yBounds.Y; i++)
                    {
                        yLevel.Clear();
                        yLevel = perimeter.FindAll(x => x.Y == i);
                        //Instead, define perimeter and area simultaneously in one method
                        //Define perimeter already finds bounds for each y level, just add area between them each loop
                        if (yLevel.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Vector2 xBounds = Bounding.GetXBounds(yLevel);
                            for (int j = (int)xBounds.X; j < (int)xBounds.Y; j++)
                            {
                                area.Add(new Vector2(j, i));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    areaDefined = true;
                }
                else if(yBounds.Y-yBounds.X==0)
                {
                    area.Add(new Vector2(yBounds.Y, yBounds.Y));
                }
            }
            else if (perimeterDefined == true && perimeter.Count == 1)
            {
                area.Add(perimeter[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Perimeter not defined!");
            }
```

The YBounds and XBounds methods are the same just swapping x for y respectively:

```
public static Vector2 GetYBounds(List<Vector2> range)
        {
                return new Vector2(range.Min(x => (int)x.Y), range.Max(x => (int)x.Y));
        }
```

So as you can see the area definition is pretty heavy performance wise. I tried a new method in which I just calculated the radius of circles that would be subtracted, and using their position determined which vector2s in the base area needed to be removed. Unfortunately, this was not much faster. Would love any performance advice. If there are any questions regarding this, please let me know!

Thanks! :)

Comment: It's not something I have any great experience with but I suspect that the GraphicsPath class may be of use.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? Or something else? The answer depends somewhat on that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Its a windows console application in Visual Studio, and all drawing/rendering happens at the end in one step and is written to a bitmap file, so there's no actual drawing or rendering "during runtime" if that's what you were thinking

Answer (score 0):

First try using [Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

This is what I would try:

```
public override void DefinePerimeter()
    {
        perimeter = new List<Vector2>();

        //Find one quadrant worth of perimeter
        //Mirror x,y values to form full circle

        // this helps to get the value to the stack wich is faster to call
        int CenterX = center.x;
        int CenterY = center.y;
        
        Parallel.ForEach(Iterate(0,90,resolutionFactor).ToArray(), (value, state,index) => 
        {
            float cos = radius * MathF.Cos(value);
            float sin = radius * MathF.Sin(value);
            // do the calculations once then just callit
            int CenterXPluszCos = (int)(CenterX + cos);
            int CenterXMinusCos = (int)(CenterX - cos);
            int CenterYMinusSin = (int)(CenterY - sin);
            int CenterYPluszSin = (int)(CenterY + sin);
            perimeter.Add(new Vector2(CenterXPluszCos, CenterYMinusSin));
            perimeter.Add(new Vector2(CenterXMinusCos , CenterYMinusSin));
            perimeter.Add(new Vector2(CenterXMinusCos, CenterYPluszSin));
            perimeter.Add(new Vector2(CenterXPluszCos , CenterYPluszSin));
        });
        perimeter = RemoveDuplicates(perimeter);//Removes duplicate Vector2
}
private static IEnumerable<double> Iterate(double FromInclusive, double toExclusive, double step)
{
   for(double d = fromInclusive; d < toExclusive; d+= step yield return d;
}
```

A if you want you can try creating a array list of perimeter and by using the index add the calculated vectors. This could be good if the Add method is slowing down the loop. But it is harder to do and 100% faster in the long run if you convert the array back to list.

Second thing I would try is this.

```
if (perimeterDefined == true && perimeter.Count>1)
        {
            Vector2 yBounds = Bounding.GetYBounds(perimeter);
            // here you can use somthing else as a variable if you dont want to Order the perimeter
            perimeter = perimeter.OrderBy(x => x.Y);
            if(yBounds.Y-yBounds.X>0)
            {
                List<Vector2> yLevel = new List<Vector2>();
                int perimeterIndex = (int)yBounds.X;
                for (int i = (int)yBounds.X; i < (int)yBounds.Y; i++)
                {
                    yLevel.Clear(); 
                    // this way the FindAll is eliminated 
                    // this is faster because  we don't check all the perimeter only what is next in the list so it is O(n)
                    while(perimeter[perimeterIndex] == i)
                    {
                        yLevel.Add(perimeter[perimeterIndex])
                        perimeterIndex++;
                    }
                    //yLevel = perimeter.FindAll(x => x.Y == i);
                    //Instead, define perimeter and area simultaneously in one method
                    //Define perimeter already finds bounds for each y level, just add area between them each loop
                    if (yLevel.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Vector2 xBounds = Bounding.GetXBounds(yLevel);
                        for (int j = (int)xBounds.X; j < (int)xBounds.Y; j++)
                        {
                            area.Add(new Vector2(j, i));
                        }
                    }
                }
                areaDefined = true;
            }
            else if(yBounds.Y-yBounds.X==0)
            {
                area.Add(new Vector2(yBounds.Y, yBounds.Y));
            }
        }
        else if (perimeterDefined == true && perimeter.Count == 1)
        {
            area.Add(perimeter[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Perimeter not defined!");
        }
```

If the second is not working or something then on thing you can do is remove the yLevel.Clear(); from the original code because the findAll will return empty list if elements not found